# Completely open-source and encrypted text, audio, and video chat software

Tags: chat

Isn't there any open-source software out there that does text, audio and video chat, in a completely secure way? Something that I can just start using "out of the box" without any pain?

The reason I ask is that I don't trust Skype, Facebook and MSN. I'm afraid that these companies have huge server farms to collect our text, audios, and videos. At least I have no reason to assume that they don't do  this. Or do I?

Comment: I'm sure Skype's this ubiquitous and well known because there are tons of better alternatives.

Comment: I investigated Ekiga for a while, but I'm not sure that it does encryption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jitsi](http://jitsi.org/) will give you most of what you want, I believe the only thing it does not encrypt at the moment is video chat. Voice and text chat are encrypted with ZRTP and OTR respectively.

Comment: // , Even Tox has better stability than Jitsi, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Ventrilo](http://www.ventrilo.com) or similar and run your own server, and simply fire everything through an SSL tunnel.

Entirely controllable by you.